# The simple meaning behind covering map & lifting

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

When it comes to math concepts, my sneaky feeling is that they were all started up as simple ideas, but got more and more convoluted as mathematicians tried harder and harder in making them more precise, rigorous, impenetrable, air-tight, waterproof and foolproof.

Continuity and limit are both painless ideas, but their $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definitions have made them torturous, with their simple ideas getting lost in transit. "Thou shalt not steal" is a very simple idea too, but wait until the lawyers finish codifying it into law.

Having said that, here are my questions:

(1) At the risk of oversimplification, is there any simple idea behind covering map? If $p: E \to B$ is a covering map, does it mean generalization of the concept of surjective mapping? Please do not give me the official definition.

(2) How about lifting? Does it mean elevating one map to higher dimension? Any physical model perhaps?

I also believe that math name was not coined in the olden days simply because the inventor though it was cute, but it was voted up and down over centuries by consensus. Therefore I think "covering" and "lifting" should somehow relate to their plain English meaning.

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: Draw a picture. A covering map does cover in the sense of the initial space evenly lying over the target. A lifting is a way of turning a function on one space into a function on a space mapping onto the first one. Do your books have any picture of the path-lifting property?  I am surprised you missed the picture associated to covering maps and liftings, thinking such terms are divorced from their everyday meaning. I'd think someone would be puzzled by the word "section" (a certain kind of function) more than by "covering map" or "lifting."

Comment: Thanks. I did see diagrams in my book, "stacks of pancake," etc., but I still do not get their intuitive meaning. I am looking for some more intuitive explanations. What do you mean by the "path-lifting property?" Do you mean the commutative triangle diagram, as in Munkres' book? That is the only one I get. Thanks again.

Comment: The real line is a covering space of the circle, and mapping the real line onto the circle by wrapping it around (by $x \mapsto (\cos x, \sin x)$) is a covering map. Mapping $\mathbf C$ onto a quotient group $\mathbf C/\Lambda$ for some lattice $\Lambda$ is a covering map.

Comment: @KCd : I think I can use your two examples $f: x \mapsto (\cos x, \sin x)$ and $g: C \to C/A$ as visualization to covering maps. But I am still curious on what you wrote about lifting. Am I correct in putting in bracket in order to clarify it? $$\text{A lifting is a way of turning a function on one space into a function on [another] space mapping onto the first one.}$$Let me know and thank you again.

Comment: Yes, that would be correct.