# Power of complex number is the degree of map

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I was given an off-the-cuff question in my topology class, the image below is copied exactly from the whiteboard:

---

[image]

---

Here are the explanation:
(1) The vertical map $e = \mathbb R \to S^1$ is the covering map, the "exponential map" from real number to circle $S^1$. If we view $S^1$ as $\{z \in \mathbb C \mid |z| = 1\}$, then $e$ is given by 
$$e(t) = \exp (2 \pi i t),$$
but if we view $S^1$ as $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$, then $e$ is given by 
$$e(t) = (\cos(2 \pi t), \sin(2 \pi t)).$$

(2) $e \restriction _{[0, 1]}$ is restriction of $e$ of $[0,1]$ 
(3) $f : S^1 \to S^1$ is not shown in the image, where $z \in \mathbb C$ and $m$ is the power of $z$ 
(4) The tilde map $\tilde f$ is the lifting of $f$ such that their composition:
$$e \restriction _{[0,1]} \circ f = e \circ \tilde f.$$ 
(5) The degree of map is defined as $\tilde f(1) - \tilde f(0) = m \in \mathbb Z$, which my professor said is independent of choice of lift $\tilde f$.

And here is the off-the-cuff question:

> Show that the degree of map $f$ is $m$.

Since I am lost on this, I would appreciate any help to prove this problem. Thank you very much for your time and help.

---

POST SCRIPT - 3/25/15: Based on the response and comments from @anomaly and @Amitai Yuval, here is answer to my own question: (Thanks to both of you!)

**SOLUTION:** 
(1)  I set the lifting of $f$ as $\tilde f(x) = mx$ and
$$\tilde f : x \in [0, 1] \longmapsto m \in \mathbb R; mx = [0, m].$$

(2) I set the covering map
$$e: r, \theta \in [0, m] \longmapsto r^m \bigl(\cos(m \theta) + i \sin(m \theta) \bigr).$$

(3) Setting $e' := e \mid_{ [0, 1]}$ as a special case of $e$ when $m = 1$ and $r, x  \in [0, 1]$, therefore
$$e' : x, \theta \in [0, 1]; m =1 \longmapsto x \bigl(\cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta)\bigr).$$

(4) Setting $f(z) = z^m$ where $z \in \mathbb C$ and $m \in \mathbb R$,
$$f: x \bigl( \cos (\theta) + i \sin(\theta) \bigr) \longmapsto x^m \bigl( cos(m \theta) + i \sin (m \theta ) \bigr).$$

(5) From the above definitions, I show that $\tilde f$ is a lifting of composition $f \circ e':$
$$\begin{align}
f \circ e' &= e \circ \tilde f\\
f \bigl (x (\cos(\theta) + i \sin (\theta))\bigr) &= e \bigl(mx \in [0, m] \subset \mathbb R \bigr)\\
\bigl (x^m (\cos(m\theta) + i \sin (m\theta))\bigr) &= \bigl (x^m (\cos(m\theta) + i \sin (m\theta))\bigr).\\
\end{align}$$

(6) And finally by definition of degree of map:
$$\begin {align}
deg (f) &= \tilde f(1) - \tilde f(0)\\
&= m - 0\\
&= m \quad \blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: You don't have to define things like covering maps or lifts. It is useful, though, to explain exactly where and why you're stuck. Are you comfortable, for example, with the definition of the degree of a map $S^1 \to S^1$? Do you have any theorems whose conclusions give you the degree of a map? What about for $S^1 \to S^1$ specifically?

Comment: There are a few different definitions for degree of which I am aware. Hence, it would be very helpful if you wrote in your post the definition you use.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval :  Oops! I have updated the posting, now it has the definition of degree of map, see (5). Sorry to both of you, thanks for pointing out though, and let me know again if something is still missing.

Comment: @anomaly : I have updated the definition of degree of map, see (5) above $-$ thanks for pointing that out though. Honestly, I know these subjects skin-deep only on a formalism level, not really get into all the intuitions behind them, therefore I got stuck even from the start. This is not the first time I am asking for help, I posted [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189010/the-simple-meaning-behind-covering-map-lifting) couple of days ago asking for intuition. Hope these explanation helps and thanks again for responding.

Comment: @A.Magnus:  With that definition of degree, the easiest way to proceed is to compute $\tilde f(1) - \tilde f(0)$ explicitly for $f(z) = z^n$. Since the degree is independent of the choice of $\tilde f$, you just need to find some explicit $\tilde f$ making the diagram commute; that is, such that $e(\tilde f t) = e(t)^n$. (I'm working with the embedding of $S^1$ in $\mathbb{C}$ throughout.) Write the last equation out explicitly and you should find a good candidate for $f$.

Comment: @anomaly : Thanks! Just to acknowledge I saw your comment, but I am still digesting slowly one word at a time... (Sigh! Slowpoke takes longer time.) I will get back with you as soon as the bulb get lit. Thanks again.

Comment: @anomaly : Not losing steam but need to do another due date work first before coming back shortly. Thanks!

Comment: @A.Magnus: Don't worry about it. Take your time.

Comment: @anomaly : See answer to my question above after getting help from you. Thanks again and again. (I keep my promise.)

Answer (score 2):

Using the above definition for degree, the simplest way to solve the question is by constructing a lift explicitly. Defining $\tilde{f}$ by $\tilde{f}(x)=mx$, one can verify that this is indeed a lift, and the proof is complete.

Comment: Thanks! I am still digesting your idea, will get back with you shortly.

Comment: Not losing steam but need to do another due date work first before coming back shortly. Thanks!

Comment: See answer to my question above after getting help from you. Thanks again and again. (I keep my promise.)